# system of differential equation question/hint

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

to solve the following system, a and b are constants
where $$ x(1)= 3$$  $$ y(0) = 0$$

$${dx \over dt} = {-2ax+by}$$ 
$${dy \over dt} = {ax-2by}$$

how do you approach it? using eigenvalue and eigenvector directly won't lead my anywhere in regard to a and b, I tried to solve each each differential equation separately first with the initial condition and it is a mess.

Comment: This might be helpful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation

Comment: Without more information, you can’t solve for $a$ and $b$. You’ll just have to consider separately the different possibilities that can arise for various values of these parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Don't be afraid of matrices containing parameters. 
Let $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ be the eigenvalues of $\pmatrix{-2a & b\cr a & -2b\cr}$
(these can be computed easily, but it may be simpler to express things in terms of them rather than carry around some complicated expressions).  The corresponding eigenvectors
can be written as $\pmatrix{b\cr \lambda_1 + 2a}$ and $\pmatrix{b\cr \lambda_2 + 2a}$.
Next you  need to express the initial vector as a linear combination of these. (I'm assuming that should be $x(0)=3$ rather than $x(1)=3$).

There is one complication: the case where the two eigenvalues coincide, but if $a$ and $b$ are real, that only happens when $a=b=0$.

Comment: I utilized matrices to solve for the eigenvalue initially. However, the general quadratic equation have three unknowns, a, b and lambda..... would you elaborate on the "the corresponding eigenvecots be written as ..", at least the theory behind it

Comment: It is a quadratic equation in one variable, $\lambda$.  $a$ and $b$ are not unknowns to solve for, they are parameters.  The usual quadratic formula applies.

Comment: As for the eigenvectors: the first row of the system $$\pmatrix{-2a & b\cr a &- 2 b\cr} \pmatrix{x\cr y\cr} = \lambda \pmatrix{x \cr y\cr}$$ is $-2a x + b y = \lambda x$.  Assuming $b \ne 0$, solve for $y$.  The form I gave (with $x = b$) also turns out to work if $b=0$.